# numpy load times (.npy file)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of ~10k numpy files (.npy) that I need to read and process in a script.  Throughout my development of this script, the time required by the load function (npyio.py) has varied dramatically, from 0.001 sec to 0.03 per call.  The number of calls to the function and the files being loaded have not changed - all that has changed is where in the script it is called.

Is there anything about the numpy.load function that's known to cause variability in loading times?

Comment: Just to be sure, the load time per call goes from 0.001 s to 0.03 s during a single execution of your script ?

Comment: Between executions.  I'm using cProfile so all I have is the average load time for each execution.

Comment: Have you checked that the OS is not swapping when you start loading the files ?

Comment: Your OS could be caching the file. When it's cached in memory, loading is much faster.

Comment: Is there a way to check for/force that behavior in this instance?